# When given the maxterm of function, we can find its minterm of the function, which is also the complement of the maxterm,

Tags: boolean-algebra

When given the maxterm of function, we can find the minterm of the function, which is also the complement of the maxterm.

When do we use one (maxterm) instead of the others (minterm/its complement)?
Or is it just pointed in text for us to notice?  I found it quite annoying, when reading the text, people use them interchangeably; I'm not not sure if they use one over the other for other reasons.

Comment: `its complement` its *dual*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> people use them interchangeably

Minterms are product terms used in a sum of products representation of a logic function.

Maxterms are sums, that are used in a product of sums representation of a logic function.

They are not the same, and should not be used interchangeably. Perhaps you saw someone write "minterm (maxterm)" where they were trying to convey some fact that is true of either.